# Android unregisterReceiver with onPause

Tags: java, android

I have something like this in my manifest file - I need one receiver for the situation that a power source was connected and the other receiver for unplugged source.

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionOnReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
            <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionOffReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But I want to unregisterReceiver, when onPause is called in my MainActivity. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your broadcast receiver is specified in the manifest, it cannot be unregistered programmatically. You will need to take it out of the manifest and register it from within your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unregister these receivers because they are defined in manifest, not in code. Receivers which are defined programmatically are the one which may get unregistered.